# Docker with Java Unable to access jarfile application.jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i'm trying to excute this command for my Spring boot application:

```bash
docker build -t api-gateways-layered -f Dockerfile.layered .
```

however i got this error

```
 => ERROR [builder 4/4] RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract                                                                                                                            0.5s
------
 > [builder 4/4] RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract:
#8 0.438 Error: Unable to access jarfile application.jar
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract]: exit code: 1
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17

COPY target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

my Dockerfile.layered

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre as builder
WORKDIR extracted
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app.jar extract

FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder extracted/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/application/ ./
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

please any fix ?

it should create an image but this is prevent me from create a image

Comment: To double-check, your `Dockerfile.layered` consistently uses `app.jar` but your error message says `application.jar`, including in the quoted `RUN` line.  Does your local environment have the same name in the `RUN` line and the `ADD` line before it?

Comment: what do you mean by "your local environment have the same name in the RUN line and the ADD line before it?"

Comment: oh i got it yes it's the same however it's not working, note: i'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

This error raised because docker cannot find MANIFEST.MF file in the jar file. You can check it by typing:

> java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar list

If you haven't fixed the issue yet, follow these steps:

1. Add this plugin:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layers>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </layers>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

2. In terminal, type:

> mvn clean package

Note: You should have maven installed locally

3. Try viewing the contents of the newly generated jar file:

> java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar list

Yous should see the following output:

```
dependencies
spring-boot-loader
snapshot-dependencies
application
```

4. Now, you can build the image by typing:

> docker build -t api-gateway-layered -f Dockerfile.layered .

You can explore more from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-docker-images) (for v3.0.0+ too), [spring-boot-2.3.0-M](https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/27/creating-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-m1/), and other sites.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the error is related to the inability to access the JAR file during the layered build. Here are some adjustments you can make to your Dockerfile.layered that may help:

Dockerfile.layered :

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine as builder
WORKDIR extracted
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app.jar extract

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder extracted/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder extracted/application/ ./
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

In this adjusted Dockerfile.layered:

The base image is switched to eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine to use a smaller Alpine Linux-based image.

The JAR file extraction should work with the corrected image.

The entry point is specified correctly as "java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher" without the extra quotation marks.

These changes should resolve the issue you encountered. Make sure to have the app.jar file in the target directory before building the Docker image.